# Performance of django-CMS with remote mysql DB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, django-cms

I have tried to run a django-CMS (+filer +easy_thumbnails) with a remote mysql DB on GoogleAppengine, with cloudstorage. After fixing file-system related performance problems and fork-fixing a django-google-cloud-storage module (http://github.com/locandy/django-google-cloud-storage), the performance is still beyond terrible (4s per request pre cache). Most things are configured as default from the tutorial.

Timing is for generic page rendering requests (no cache, not logged in, excluding instance start up time). The fastest is an empty page (no images, no text) with 1.7 seconds and 40 database RPCs. The slowest a full page with many images and some text at 4 seconds and 100 rdbms.Exec calls. I used the appengine python profiling module.

On average that would be 45ms per query.

**Is there any configuration we have missed?**

**Did anyone succeed in deploying a CMS in the cloud with remote DB that is usable?**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms',
```

Profiling:

```
  (1) 2014-01-15 12:15:03.358 "GET .../benefits/" 200 real=4636ms api=0ms overhead=9ms (89 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
  (2) 2014-01-15 12:14:56.862 "GET .../preise/" 200 real=5200ms api=0ms overhead=9ms (94 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
  (3) 2014-01-15 12:14:47.673 "GET .../einstieg/" 200 real=4684ms api=0ms overhead=8ms (87 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
  (4) 2014-01-15 12:14:01.054 "GET .../moeglichkeiten/" 200 real=5341ms api=0ms overhead=10ms (98 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
  (5) 2014-01-15 12:13:31.516 "GET .../werkzeuge/" 200 real=5176ms api=0ms overhead=9ms (96 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
  (6) 2014-01-15 12:13:00.507 "GET .../einstieg/" 200 real=5460ms api=0ms overhead=9ms (94 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
  (7) 2014-01-15 12:12:59.891 "GET .../" 302 real=369ms api=0ms overhead=0ms (7 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly which requests are taking 4s?

Comment: Generic page rendering requests (no cache). The fastest is an empty page (no images, no text) with 1.7 seconds and 40 database RPCs. The slowest a full page with many images and some text at 4 seconds.

Comment: But that's *your* latency. You'll need to dig in and see what those 96 RPCs are doing - you should take a look at an appstats trace

Comment: For my purpose django-CMS is an off-the-shelf product, this is not a custom appengine application that I can control. There are only 2 conclusions here: (1) its misconfigured, (2) the software does not work on appengine and I need a single Linux box. The 96 RPCs are queries by the CMS to the CloudSQL. I have fixed all cloud-storage access by configuration and bug reports to the middleware module authors.

Comment: To be fair I need to add that if its not a configuration problem one would encounter the same problems on Amazon Beanstalk with S3 and it would be a generic cloud incompatibility.

Comment: 40 database queries for an empty page load is a little ridiculous... looks like this is a django-CMS issue. Can you reduce the number of queries somehow?

Comment: There are already 5 queries to produce a redirect/302 from page to page/, just to mention it. The "empty" page is header and footer without content, produced by a webdesigner. The image plugin produces 1 query per image to check if the thumbnail is up to date. Basically I think that 40 queries is what every LAMP-CMS does today: http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/07/12/how-many-queries-are-too-many/ http://www.blue-dreamer.co.uk/blog/entry/reducing-database-queries-in-expressionengine so maybe the answer is that there is no cloud-ready scalable open-source CMS today?

Comment: Could you post a trace from appstats? That would be really helpful to see what's going on.

Comment: Profiling above is already a trace of appstats. I have confirmed that django-CMS makes too many sequential SQL queries to be usable. A really empty page will produce 11 queries (rdbms.Exec 11) 11*40ms = ~440ms.

Answer (score 1):

After profiling django-CMS with appstats in the recommended setup with filer and easy-thumbnails and after excluding cloudstorage, it is not possible to render new uncached **empty** pages in less than 500ms with a remote DB.

Every placeholder or feature added to a page adds several **sequentially executed** queries. A complex page has up to 100 queries and a moderate page about 50. This adds up to 4-5 seconds rendering time for a page.

We have run a remote DB connection to a SDK instance on a local machine Europe-USA, which increased the page rendering time to 32 seconds. Access times seems to scale linear with network delay and number of queries.

The system can still be used with django's database cache, but the administrative backend is too slow to be used conveniently. Conclusion: django-CMS is not compatible with a remote DB setting in any cloud.

As a result of our tests we have fixed a uncached django storage module compatible with cloudstorage
http://github.com/locandy/django-google-cloud-storage

Comment: Have you considered running it on a GCE machine, storing the DB on a PD volume?