# Fastest Open Source Content Management System for Cloud/Cluster deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, amazon-web-services, content-management-system

Currently clouds are mushrooming like crazy and people start to deploy everything to the cloud including CMS systems, but so far I have not seen people that have succeeded in deploying popular CMS systems to a load balanced cluster in the cloud. Some performance hurdles seem to prevent standard open-source CMS systems to be deployed to the cloud like this.

CLOUD: A cloud, better load-balanced cluster, has at least one frontend-server, one network-connected(!) database-server and one cloud-storage server. This fits well to Amazon Beanstalk and Google Appengine. (This specifically excludes CMS on a single computer or Linux server with MySQL on the same "CPU".)

To deploy a standard CMS in such a load balanced cluster needs a cloud-ready CMS with the following characteristics:

- The CMS must deal with the latency of queries to still be responsive and render pages in less than a second to be cached (or use a precaching strategy)
- The filesystem probably must be connected to a remote storage (Amazon S3, Google cloudstorage, etc.)

Currently I know of python/django and Wordpress having middleware modules or plugins that can connect to cloud storages instead of a filesystem, but there might be other cloud-ready CMS implementations (Java, PHP, ?) and systems.

I myself have failed to deploy django-CMS to the cloud, finally due to query latency of the remote DB. So here is my question:

**Did you deploy an open-source CMS that still performs well in rendering pages and backend admin? Please post your average page rendering access stats in microseconds for uncached pages.**

**IMPORTANT: Please describe your configuration, the problems you have encountered, which modules had to be optimized in the CMS to make it work, don't post simple "this works", contribute your experience and knowledge.**

Such a CMS probably has to make fewer than 10 queries per page, if more, the queries must be made in parallel, and deal with filesystem access times of 100ms for a stat and query delays of 40ms.

Related:

- [Slow MySQL Remote Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558502/slow-mysql-remote-connection)

Comment: I'm a little confused...  CMS systems primarily rely on a database...  What are you using cloud storage for if you already have an on-site DB?

Comment: Cloud storage stores binary files, images, videos (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_storage) whatever the CMS usually stores on the Linux file system outside of the DB. The cloudstorage can usually be configured to serve content as a static website without intervention of the CMS.

Comment: I think AppEngine (because you ask here) is uncompetitive for a CMS workload because the Datastore is designed for large numbers of small records, while Content is often smaller numbers of bigger documents.  The best price/performance option to store documents is a filesystem, and AppEngine and other Cloud platforms have to deny the web application filesystem access.  Only the Blobstore in AppEngine could store files, but that's a key-value structure without folders, permissions and so on.  In short, the feature set of AppEngine and other Cloud platforms is not suitable enough for CMS use.

Comment: Martin, you have to update your knowledge about cloudstore and its appengine integration. Google CloudStore is kind of a filesystem for Appengine and a static website too. The Appengine can also use the CloudSQL instead of the Datastore. This is how we installed django-CMS (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137634/performance-of-django-cms-with-remote-mysql-db) It just does not perform well, because 40 queries to render a page take 2 seconds. Its like running a current CMS on 10 years old hardware, with huge harddisks.

Comment: You can't out-code the laws of physics, and a distant database is a recipe for "slow."  You also can't just arbitrarily redefine "cloud" here, and it is particularly unreasonable to specify that the filesystem be housed in Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage, since there is a significant impedance mismatch between what those services are ... and what a filesystem is.  Those are the wrong tools, so, they don't work well when you use them in place of more appropriate ones.  Shopping list questions centered around "Does anyone know any..." are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: A lot of bogus discussions on here. Guys dont even consider the 'advice' given in these comments.

Comment: I agree Zig. Please, everyone, take out emotion. This is about finding  open-source cloud-deployable CMS systems that address the "significant impedance mismatch" of the cloud, as Michael pointed it out correctly.

Comment: @cat There is nothing about emotion here; as noted in several places on this site, shopping list questions are off topic.

Comment: @Daedalus how can we fix the question to not be a shopping list question (help me to design such a question), but still reach the goal to find CMS systems or configurations of those that work in a load balanced remote DB setting? Currently the myth exists that the cloud is fast and one can deploy a LAMP CMS to the cloud. I am kind of surprised that people think the laws of physics prevent a CMS in the cloud.

Comment: @cat Check out [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), it discusses such a topic, and is what introduced SO to that particular close reason.  If you want something specific for your question, I can't oblige; I don't really see a way to improve it.  Asking for lists of things means there isn't really a right answer.. its all subjective.

Comment: I have changed the question, now its no longer can tagged as shopping-list and has quantifiable results, but still reaches the goal to find systems that work (which as of today should not be plenty).

Comment: @cat I disagree; 'fastest' is still subjective, and you're still asking for multiple answers where there is no 'right' answer.

Comment: Fastest is not subjective. I could ask for a benchmark, but that would    put the bar too high for any answers. Fact is that I expect there exist 1-7 CMS systems that work in the cloud. I cannot find them without people trying to deploy them. We lost about 120h work in trying the wrong CMS. Anyway this discussion here obviously is off topic because of the discussion if this question is valid exceeds content.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Umbraco?

It relies on database, but it keeps layers of cache so you arent doing selects on every request.

http://umbraco.com/azure

It works great on azure too!

Comment: This one qualifies according to wikipedia: "Umbraco sites which serve content under higher load can also be deployed on a load balanced cluster" (source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbraco )

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to deploy python django-CMS (www.django-cms.org) on GoogleAppEngine with CloudSQL as DB and CloudStore as Filesystem. Cloud store was attached by forking and fixing a django.storage module by Christos Kopanos http://github.com/locandy/django-google-cloud-storage

After that, the second set of problems came up as we discovered we had access times of up to 17s for a single page access. We have investigated this and found that easy-thumbnails 1.4 accessed the normal file system for mod_time requests while writing results to the store (rendering all thumb images on every request). We switched to the development version where that was already fixed.

Then we worked with SmileyChris to fix unnecessary access of mod_times (stat the file) on every request for every image by tracing and posting issues to http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails

This reduced access times from 12-17s to 4-6s per public page on the CMS basically eliminating all storage/"file"-system access. Once that was fixed, easy-thumbnails replaced (per design) file-system accesses with queries to the DB to check on every request if a thumbnail's source image has changed.

One thing for the web-designer: if she uses a image.width statement in the template this forces a ugly slow read on the "filesystem", because image widths are not cached.

Further investigation led to the conclusion that DB accesses are very costly, too and take about 40ms per roundtrip.

Up to now the deployment is unsuccessful mostly due to DB access times in the cloud leading to 4-5s delays on rendering a page before caching it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an excellent performance test of Wordpress on Appengine. It appears that Google has spent some time to optimize this system for load-balanced cluster and remote DB deployment:

http://www.syseleven.de/blog/4118/google-app-engine-php/

Scaling test from the report.

```
parallel
hits    GAE  1&1  Sys11
1       1,5  2,6    8,5
10      9,8  8,5   69,4
100    14,9   -   146,1
```

Conclusion from the report the system is slower than on traditional hosting but scales much better.

http://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress